# Windows QueueUserWorkItem C++ Release mode issue

Tags: c++, windows, release, threadpool

I have c++ code that uses QueueUserWorkItem to call a function that from a wrapper class that calls winsock accept. This works fine in debug, it also works if I run the release executable from using the Start Profile option from Dependency Walker. However if I run the release executable normally, it crashes on the call to QueueUserWorkItem. As soon as it calls that function the application just exits. Execution never reaches the function I pass into QueueUserWorkItem, however the function pointer is valid.

Does anyone know of anything that could cause QueueUserWorkItem to crash in release mode but not debug?

Comment: Crashes that involve QUWI and are affected by tooling are usually caused by threading races.  The changed timing can trigger them.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know of anything that could cause `<random function>` to crash in release mode but not debug?

Yes, buffer overflows. Debug build have guards placed around them that you can overwrite, but in Release mode you're probably overwriting important memory.

Comment: Yes, among other things... "Surviving the Release Version" is a common reference: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/survivereleasever.aspx